# Thread with priority settings

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

I just made a countdown app with three threads including the main thread. I have CountdownEven set to low so that countdownOdd will display first but in the output nothing is happening. Can anyone see the problem?

```
//Main
public class CountdownApp 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    new CountdownApp().start();

    }
    public void start()
    {
        Thread count1 = new CountdownEven();
        Thread count2 = new CountdownOdd();
        count1.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        count2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        count1.start();
        count2.start();
    }

}


public class CountdownEven extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 10; i > 0; i-=2)
        {
            System.out.println(this.getName()+ " Count: " +i);
            Thread.yield();//This is to allow the other thread to run.
    }
    }


}

public class CountdownOdd extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 9; i > 0; i-=2)
        {
            System.out.println(this.getName()+ " Count: " +i);
            Thread.yield();//This is to allow the other thread to run.
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Setting the priority won't guarantee the execution order, especially on a such short period.

Comment: I just ran your code and I get an output : `Thread-1 Count: 9` / `Thread-1 Count: 7` / `Thread-1 Count: 5` etc.

Comment: Using priorities is not the right way to define the order in which your threads will run.

Comment: @assylias Weird, I just ran it as well, and got the expected output (10, 9, 8, ...). But that may just be luck. It's definitely not the way to order things.

Comment: Compiles and runs well for me. Well, the output might not be as expected as using thread priorities isn't suited for what seems like the intended purpose. So to answer the q: "No,I can't see the problem, as there is no problem for me."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it does produce an output.

```
Thread-0 Count: 10
Thread-0 Count: 8
Thread-0 Count: 6
Thread-0 Count: 4
Thread-0 Count: 2
Thread-1 Count: 9
Thread-1 Count: 7
Thread-1 Count: 5
Thread-1 Count: 3
Thread-1 Count: 1
```

Exactly the output as it should be... so whats your prob?
Maybe you just have to open a new console widget/tab in eclipse or you have any active filter?

But imho I wont use Threadpriorities for this purpose, see
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: +1: Even if your OS doesn't ignore the hint, if you have plenty of free CPU every thread which would like to run, will run regardless of priority.

Comment: I would add that using thread priorities 1) is platform specific 2) is not guaranteed to work and 3) can lead in some extreme cases to some threads never being executed (starvation).